# Adding an index without a lag (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, performance, index, postgresql-performance

PostgreSQL:

Adding an index to a table with big amount of data causes a lag for both `SELECT` and `INSERT` operations on that table, doesn't it?

While PostgreSQL does not support live (without lags) adding of indexes, how to solve the problem of adding an index to a table without lagging `SELECT` and `INSERT` (there is no `UPDATE`s on that table)?

My idea is to copy the table by small chunks to another table with the same structure, then in a transaction delete the original table and rename the new table to the original table name. How to ensure that the entire data is copied, while `INSERT` operations to the old table may happen?

Answer (score 2):

See [Building Indexes Concurrently](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-CONCURRENTLY) in PostgreSQL documentation.

`CONCURRENTLY` option of `CREATE INDEX` solves the problem in an easy way. Just add it to `CREATE INDEX`.

Be aware that while `CONCURRENTLY` option avoids lags, it does slow down building the index and that `CREATE INDEX` with `CONCURRENTLY` cannot be used in a transaction.